# What is %some property% expression in spring

Tags: spring, spring-expression

I found **%%** expression on spring batch source.
Is this SpEL? How do I use **%%** expression?

```
protected String getQuery(String base) {
    return StringUtils.replace(base, "%PREFIX%", tablePrefix);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plZwk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izM7T.png)

Comment: Hi  Can you copy paste Spring code in your question instead of providing a picture ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not spel. It's used to replace the string with some target value.
For example,

```
String base = "How are me?";
String target = "me";
String replacement = "you";
String result = StringUtils.replace(base, target, replacement);
```

Comment: Thank you,I know replace util, I want to know what "%PREFIX%" expression is and how to use this.

Comment: it is used to modify the template query. See this =>
private static final String  SQL_DELETE_BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION = "DELETE FROM %PREFIX%JOB_EXECUTION where CREATE_TIME < ?";

Comment: Thank you.. just expression to replace the string... I was confused